# pygame and tiled map collsions

Tags: python, pygame, tiled

I am trying to make the player sprite stop falling on the platform rect top. I have tried a lot of things over the past two days and I am more lost then I've ever been. Thank you so much. I am using tmx to load a tiled map. I add a Platform object every the name is detected and than I add that to a list. I enumerate through the list to check collision using sprite.collide(self.player, plat). This doesn't work.

```
def update(self):
    for plat in self.platList:
        self.hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player,self.platList,False)
        if self.hits:
            if self.player.pos.y > self.hits[0].y:
                self.player.pos.y = self.hits[0].rect.top

 for tile in self.map.tmxdata.objects:
        if tile.name == "player":
            self.player = Player(self,tile.x,tile.y)
        if tile.name == "Platform":
            self.platList.append(Platform(self, tile.x, tile.y,tile.width,tile.height))
class Platform(pg.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self,game,x,y,width,height):
    self.game = game
    pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.rect = pg.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    self.y = y
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y
```

Comment: In future, remember to [format your code correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). At the moment your code is not properly indented.

Comment: Please show us a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe your goals and problems as clearly as possible, otherwise we can't give you a definitive answer and you'll only get guessed and maybe misleading answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your problem is that you don't use the player's `rect` attribute to define the position of the player. You're using pygame's sprites, so use them the way it is intended.

All pygame functions that deal with sprites (e.g. `spritecollide`) will use the `rect` attribute, but in your code the player class has an additional `pos` attribute, and `Platform` also has a `y` attribute.

Remove them, and use `rect` exclusively to store the size and position of your sprites.

When you want to move a sprite, just change its `rect` (e.g. with `move_ip` etc.) or its attributes.